# Where is this piece from?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Does anyone know where is this tree from?
I found it in my childhood (90s) box full of LEGO, but I'm pretty sure it is not actually LEGO.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any markings of LEGO anywhere on it? Nearly every piece has it imprinted somewhere.

Comment: Doesn't look like LEGO in the slightest. Wrong texture, no studs or anti-studs, wrong color...

Answer (score 3):

It is not LEGO. Parts from the 90s are well documented, and I can't find this part on [BrickLink when searching for the word "Tree"](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&q=tree&catLike=W&sortBy=D&sortAsc=D&catType=P).